# Imutils installed but python gives error "No module named imutils"

Tags: python, import, imutils

I installed imutils on python 3.7 but every time I use import imutils it gives me an error  "no module names imutils".

This is what I've done so far:

- I am using MacBook and have tried using pycharm and Python IDE interface both but both give the same error.
- I used pycharm to install imutils and then used 
  pip install imutils as well. 
  Tried : sudo pip install imutils
- sudo pip3 install imutils
- sudo -H. pip install imutils
- restarted the machine
  None of these seem to work
- I am not using anaconda or any virtual env. 
  The python 3.7 is on the osX.

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed. One you used to install module and second to run code. Check `pip3 -V` and `python -V`. You can also use python to install module - `python -m pip install imutils`.

Comment: you can also check if you have commands `pip3.5`, `pip3.6`, `pip3.7` and `python3.5`, `python3.6`, `python3.7`

Answer (score -3):

Please check if you imported imutils in your Python Code

```
import imutils
```

Also make sure you have only one version of python installed.

Comment: The question says that they tried to do import imutils, and that is what gives the error.